# Why do I have problems with TensorFlow in Jupyter?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I have been fine with my Jupyter notebook for running my python codes for some time. However, I recently picked interests in Style Transfer with deep learning. The codes I got for practice required that I downgrade TensorFlow to a lower version. Fortunately, this worked but unfortunately, all other codes that I have developed for months (requiring TensorFlow backend) stopped working. I tried using JupyterLab and sometimes, they worked while most times, I get the same error just as in Jupyter notebook. Now, the only get around is to move my codes to Spyder (which is quite frustrating). 
Every time I run my codes, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-6d5587dfcc0c> in <module>
  1 # import all libraries
----> 2 import keras
  3 from keras.models import Sequential
  4 from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
  5 from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
  1 from __future__ import absolute_import
  2 
----> 3 from . import utils
  4 from . import activations
  5 from . import applications

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py in <module>
  4 from . import data_utils
  5 from . import io_utils
----> 6 from . import conv_utils
  7 
  8 # Globally-importable utils.

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py in <module>
  7 from six.moves import range
  8 import numpy as np
----> 9 from .. import backend as K
 10 
 11 

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py in <module>
 87 elif _BACKEND == 'tensorflow':
 88     sys.stderr.write('Using TensorFlow backend.\n')
---> 89     from .tensorflow_backend import *
 90 else:
 91     # Try and load external backend.

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in <module>
  3 from __future__ import print_function
  4 
----> 5 import tensorflow as tf
  6 from tensorflow.python.framework import ops as tf_ops
  7 from tensorflow.python.training import moving_averages

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
 22 
 23 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
 25 
 26 try:

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
 86 # Bring in subpackages.
 87 from tensorflow.python import data
---> 88 from tensorflow.python import keras
 89 from tensorflow.python.feature_column import feature_column_lib as feature_column
 90 from tensorflow.python.layers import layers

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\__init__.py in <module>
 23 
 24 from tensorflow.python.keras import activations
---> 25 from tensorflow.python.keras import applications
 26 from tensorflow.python.keras import backend
 27 from tensorflow.python.keras import callbacks

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\applications\__init__.py in 
<module>
 23 
 24 from tensorflow.python.keras import backend
---> 25 from tensorflow.python.keras import engine
 26 from tensorflow.python.keras import layers
 27 from tensorflow.python.keras import models

 ~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\__init__.py in 
 <module>
 21 # TODO(fchollet): Remove hourglass imports once external code is done importing
 22 # non-public APIs.
---> 23 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer import InputSpec
 24 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer import Layer
 25 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer import Input

 ~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in 
 <module>
 37 from tensorflow.python.keras import initializers
 38 from tensorflow.python.keras import regularizers
---> 39 from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import generic_utils
 40 from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import tf_utils
 41 # A module that only depends on `keras.layers` import these from here.

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\__init__.py in <module>
 30 from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.generic_utils import Progbar
 31 from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.generic_utils import serialize_keras_object
---> 32 from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.io_utils import HDF5Matrix
 33 from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.layer_utils import convert_all_kernels_in_model
 34 from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.layer_utils import get_source_inputs

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\io_utils.py in <module>
 27 
 28 try:
---> 29   import h5py
 30 except ImportError:
 31   h5py = None

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py in <module>
 32         raise
 33 
---> 34 from . import version
 35 
 36 if version.hdf5_version_tuple != version.hdf5_built_version_tuple:

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\h5py\version.py in <module>
 15 
 16 from collections import namedtuple
---> 17 from . import h5 as _h5
 18 import sys
 19 import numpy

h5py\h5.pyx in init h5py.h5()

AttributeError: type object 'h5py.h5.H5PYConfig' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
```

How do I rectify this situation?
Many thanks in anticipation of your suggestions.

Comment: What does `tf.__version__` print out in Jupyter and Spyder? Is that the expected tensorflow version?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem by just importing h5py?

Comment: @ mirekphd, I dont get your question

Comment: @Matias Valdenegro, kindly please explain your suggestion!

Comment: Its simple, do you get the same error if you import h5py ?

Comment: Try to execute a new cell in Jupyter with `!pip freeze | grep tensorflow` and then in a new cell: `print(tf.__version__)`

Comment: @Matias Valdenegro, I tried import h5py. Still the same errors!

Comment: @mirekphd, I have tried this. I got the same errors. Many thanks!

Comment: @Dean: so Tensorflow versions are the same in the working (Spyder, Lab) and faulty (Notebook) setups? Strange, I would think that Notebook's python kernel has an incorrectly upgraded TF version...

Comment: Many thanks to all of you guys. Your comments have led me to a solution to the problem. I discovered my jupyter notebook was using TensorFlow from Miniconda while Spyder is pointing to Anaconda (I have the two installed on my machine). I deleted my Miniconda and installed a fresh installation of TF pointing to Anaconda. TensorFlow works fine now. I appreciate you all.